# QPainter drawText() inside while-loop

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I'm painting this inside a reimplemented QGraphicsView::drawForeground().

Say there is two records in the map. Then this will only paint the first entry in the map, and not the second. Do I need the save() and restore()?

Can't figure out the reason why the second one won't paint. My qDebug at the third last line prints out both entries, so apparently both numbers are at least stored.

```
QMapIterator<int, QPointF> it(carNumbers);
while(it.hasNext()){
  it.next();
  painter->translate(it.value());
  QTransform oldTransform = painter->transform();
  painter->setTransform(QTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, oldTransform.m31(), oldTransform.m32()));
  painter->setPen(QPen(Qt::black));
  qDebug() << it.key();
  painter->drawText(QPointF(0.0, 0.0), QString::number(it.key()));
}
```

One more question:
I get the number drawn at the expected position. That's what the translate() does, right? So then the QpointF in drawText() will be the offset from the translated point?

Comment: Get rid of your transforms and just see if the drawing code works first.  Correct me if I'm wrong, but you seem to be translating the painter, then getting it's transformation, and applying it again?  What are trying to do?

Comment: Drawing code works. Anyway, found a solution; just adding save() in  the start of the while-loop and restore() at the end, made this work. The code is basically taken from other examples I've found.